# Generalized Bayesian estimator (rule) of θ

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, estimation, decision-theory, point-estimation

Question:

Let $X_1, · · · , X_n$ be a random sample from $Poisson(θ)$. The prior for θ is $G(α, β)$

1. Find the Bayesian estimator (rule) of θ under the SEL(squared error loss).
2. Find the generalized Bayesian estimator (rule) of θ under the loss $L(θ, a) = (a−θ)^2/θ$.

Solution:

My understanding:

Assume the prior distribution $θ ∼ G(α, β)$ and suppose that we observe a sample of n Poisson data. Then, we can derive the posterior distribution via Bayes theorem as:

$θ|x ∼ G(α + n \bar{x}, β + n)$

We have squared loss, $L(\theta-a)=(\theta-a)^2$. Then the Bayes rule will be
$E[\theta|x]=?$

Then I couldn't go further from here. I wanted to make sense of the theory from  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator). But it didn't help. I appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: Your Wikipedia link (if you repair it) says "Using the MSE as risk, the Bayes estimate of the unknown parameter is simply the mean of the posterior distribution" so for 1 you want the mean of your posterior Gamma distribution

Comment: Hey , I am self learning  bayesian inference these days , and when we have prior distribution  , we multiply it with given distribution of x , $ \theta $  to get their joint distribution  , and after the joint distribution  by integrating over $ \theta $ we get the distribution  of x  , can you please show the part to determine the distribution of x , I tried but something isn't getting right ,                                                                       ,      
   Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Part 1

You want to minimize the posterior expectation of the loss.

For the squared loss, you want to minimize $E\left[(\hat\theta - \theta_{posterior})^2 \right]$.

- This is like the 2nd moment of the distribution of $\theta_{posterior}$ about the point $\hat \theta$ (the estimate).
- It is equal to the variance of the posterior gamma distribution plus the square of the distance between the estimate $\hat\theta$ and the mean of the posterior gamma distribution. $$E\left[(\hat\theta - \theta)^2 \right] = \text{Var}(\theta) +  (\hat\theta - E\left[\theta_{posterior}\right])^2$$
- This is minimized when $\hat\theta = E\left[\theta_{posterior}\right]$
- The mean of the posterior gamma distribution is described by $$E[\theta_{posterior}] = \frac{\alpha_{posterior}}{\beta_{posterior}}$$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Properties
- We can fill in $\alpha_{posterior} = \alpha + n\bar{x}$ and $\beta_{posterior} = \beta + n$
- So the estimator that minimises the posterior expectation of the loss is $$\hat{\theta} = \frac{\alpha + n\bar{x}}{\beta + n}$$

#### Part 2

For the generalized loss you want to minimize $E\left[(\hat\theta - \theta)^2 / \theta \right]$.  This you can compute by considering the integration formula for expectations with gamma functions

$$\begin{array}{}
E\left[ (a-x)^2/x \right] &=& \int_0^\infty (a-x)^2/x \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x} dx \\
&=&  \int_0^\infty (a-x)^2 \frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}x^{\alpha-2}e^{-\beta x} dx \\
&=&  \beta \frac{\Gamma(\alpha-1)}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \int_0^\infty (a-x)^2 \frac{\beta^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha-1)}x^{\alpha-2}e^{-\beta x} dx \\
\end{array}$$

and so you can compute the expectation $E\left[ (a-x)^2/x \right]$ for a gamma function as the expectation $E\left[ (a-x)^2 \right]$ for another gamma function where the parameter $\alpha$ is one less (and multiply by a constant $\beta \frac{\Gamma(\alpha-1)}{\Gamma(\alpha)} = \beta/(\alpha-1)$). So like above for the squared loss, the estimate is again the same as the mean of the posterior gamma distribution, but with $\alpha$ one less (this happens to be the maximum/mode of the posterior gamma distribution).

Comment: How did you compute the estimator that minimizes the loss ? I see that Wikipedia shows the same result. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator

Comment: @ForestGump I just looked up the mean of a gamma distribution. Or did you mean how I know that the estimator should be the mean?

Comment: How did u get this $\hat{\theta} = \frac{\alpha + n\bar{x}}{\beta + n}$?

Comment: @ForestGump I have worked out now the derivation in different steps, in the answer.

Comment: How did u find  $\alpha_{posterior} = \alpha + n\bar{x}$ and $\beta_{posterior} = \beta + n$?

Comment: You mentioned this in your own post $$θ|x ∼ G(α + n \bar{x}, β + n)$$ Is the question about how to derive the posterior? It is obtained by multiplying the prior gamma distribution with the likelihood function (for the Poisson distributed results).